# Gazebo simulation with robot arm interacting with floating item

Tags: ros, gazebo

I am trying to build a simulation where I can test my control scheme of robot arm to impose accurate force on a floating item.

I have found online how to build a robot model in Gazebo and control it using Ros. Also I have found online how to using the hydraulics plugin to build a pool but it seems like it is usually for testing underwater robots.

I am wondering if there is any tutorial or case study that I can build a pool and put a floating item in the Gazebo world and then control the robot arm under the interaction with the floating item.

Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated! Thanks a lot.